# Как расположить iframe'ы в ряд?

Tags: вёрстка, html5

Сабж. `display: inline;` ничего не меняет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если они вписываются по ширине в определенную область, то и делать ничего особенно не надо, а если по ширине они больше, чем родительский элемент, то ничего не поможет.
[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/6YmTe/)

Comment: Ну почему же не поможет?.. Можно же сделать DIV с шириной большей размера окна, а в него вставить фреймы ваши. Ваш код:

     <div style="width:1024px;">
<iframe src="http://hashcode.ru/questions/99139/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-iframe-%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4" width="300" height="200"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://hashcode.ru" width="300" height="200"></iframe>
</div>

Comment: И получим горизонтальную прокрутку? Такие варианты я даже не рассматриваю.

Comment: Спасибо, проблема была именно в этом. Но, к примеру, iframe ниже, который сам по себе был длинее экрана - просто создал полосу прокрутки, а эти не хотели влезать.